# What's the difference between a Windows language pack and a native Windows installation in that language?

Tags: windows

I am wondering -- from an application standpoint -- what the difference is between a native Windows installation (Say, in English) and a Windows version that has a language pack (say a Russian Windows with an English language pack). If you have a application that uses the operating system language to determine some things (like localised text on standard buttons), will the application still think of the Russian Windows with an English language pack as an English installation if Windows is switched to that language?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or no, because:

From the [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultuilanguage) function:

> Returns the language identifier for the user UI language for the current user.

> If the user UI language is part of a Language Interface Pack (LIP) and
> corresponds to a supplemental locale, this function returns
> LOCALE_CUSTOM_UI_DEFAULT.

Edit:

This applied for Windows Vista or later only, meaning yes, if you want the app to be compatible with Windows Me, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, it's no.